# Cannot install voyager for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, voyager

I'm trying to install voyager in my project but I keep getting an error.

I run `composer require tcg/voyager` that works. The framework gets installed.

Next I run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider=VoyagerServiceProvider` that also works

Next I run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider=ImageServiceProvider` that also works

Now when I try to run `php artisan voyager:install` I get `In Dispatcher.php line 281: Illegal offset type in isset or empty`

How can I resolve this issue? I've already tried clearing cache, config and I reinstalled but I keep getting the error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the latest version of Voyager on a more recent version of Laravel.

If this doesn't help, you can get instant help on their Slack channel.

[Laravel Voyager Slack channel](https://laravel-voyager.slack.com/)